# Twitter bootstrap : How to display popup value in text-box

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I designed one input text-box with button.Once i click the button is show one popup.Popup contains table with values.Now i selected one value but is no display in text-box.

How to get value?.Please guide me.

```
<div>
<label for="name" style="margin: 0px;">EMP NAME</label>
<input type="text" class="input-normal" id="empname" href="#fee-details" data-toggle="modal" style="line-height: initial; margin-left: 6px;">
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="fee-details" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="fee-details-label" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-body">
        <table class="table table-condensed">
            <thead class="modal-header login-modal-header">
                <tr style="width:100%;">
                    <th style="width:50%;">Header1</th>
                    <th style="width:50%;">Header2</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody class="body">
                <tr>
                    <td>1</th>
                    <td class='val'>A</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>2</th>
                    <td class='val'>B</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>3</th>
                    <td class='val'>C</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>4</th>
                    <td class='val'>D</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>5</th>
                    <td class='val'>E</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>6</th>
                    <td class='val'>F</th>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>          
    </div>
</div><!-- /.modal-content -->
</div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
```

script:

```
$('.body').on('click',function(){
$('#empname').val($(this).find('.val').html());
$('#fee-details').modal('toggle');
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can pass a clicked value in the table "back" to the `<input>` this way :

```
$("#values tbody td").on('click', function() {
    $("#empname").val($(this).text());
    $("#fee-details").modal('hide');
})
```

your code in a fiddle -> **http://jsfiddle.net/mwfbs3bk/**

NB : Have given the table an `id` for convenience

---

**Update** with a small typeahead example. The original bootstrap 2.x easy-to-use typeahead was removed from bootstrap 3.x. Fortunetely it is very, very easy to reimplement. It is just to extract the old source and include it in the project. Here it is already done for you -> **https://github.com/bassjobsen/Bootstrap-3-Typeahead**

Simply include the script

```html
<script src="https://rawgithub.com/bassjobsen/Bootstrap-3-Typeahead/master/bootstrap3-typeahead.js"></script>
```

convert your `#empname` `<input>` to a typeahead this way :

```js
$("#empname").typeahead({ source: ['London', 'Copenhagen', 'Antwerpen', 'Stockholm', 'Berlin'] });
```

updated fiddle from above -> **http://jsfiddle.net/mwfbs3bk/2/**

Comment: :Hi,now i want that popup is display  in onfocus event.It means once i trying enter name in text box it display table with values.I think that property is 'autocomplete'.

Comment: @NavyaPrasad, OK - that is called a typeahead ...? It is something completely else. So you are actually thinking of a typeahead, not a modal?

Comment: @NavyaPrasad - Yes, it is far from the original question but see update.

Comment: You are entered static values.I want table with values already i created.I removed select value button permanently.

Comment: @NavyaPrasad, yes - this is an **example** of how to use integrate a typeahead, I hope you can figure out the rest - just pass a dynamic array of values, JSON objects or whatever instead. The link above has detailed instructions how.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this in jquery. Tested the code, working fine.

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.tableBody tr').on('click', function() {

        $('#empname').val($(this).find('.val').html());
        $('#fee-details').modal('toggle');
      });
    });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <label for="name" style="margin: 0px;">EMP NAME</label>
  <input type="text" class="input-normal" id="empname" style="line-height: initial; margin-left: 6px;">
  <button type="button" id="name_value" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" href="#fee-details" data-toggle="modal">Select Value</button>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="fee-details" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="fee-details-label" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <table class="table table-condensed">
          <thead class="modal-header login-modal-header">
            <tr style="width:100%;">
              <th style="width:50%;">Header1</th>
              <th style="width:50%;">Header2</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody class="tableBody">
            <tr>
              <td>1</th>
                <td class="val">A</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>2</th>
                <td class="val">B</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>3</th>
                <td class="val">C</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>4</th>
                <td class="val">D</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>5</th>
                <td class="val">E</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>6</th>
                <td class="val">F</th>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
```

Comment: do you have changed your <td> to <td class="val"> and <tbody> to  <tbody class="tableBody">  ?

Answer (score 1):

here is just need to write few lines of jquery that will help you to make that

```css
$('tbody td').on('click',function(){
    var selectedVal = $(this).text().trim();   
    $('#empname').val(selectedVal);
    $("#fee-details").modal('hide');
})
```

and here is the demo code for this

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Vq6gt/124/)**

**[With Fixed Header table](http://jsfiddle.net/Vq6gt/126/)**

Comment: @NavyaPrasad hey it's working for me let me know code if is there any change in in

Comment: yes,I removed select value button.So now i click text-box it displayed popup and value also selected but only one value is displaying in text-box.It means first click the text-box is display popup,now i selected any value but it displaying first value(top value of the table).

Comment: @NavyaPrasad please update your code in the question and mention as updated code

Comment: Hi,updated my code in the question.Please check it once

Comment: @NavyaPrasad hey please check it's working for me here in jsfiddle please take a look **http://jsfiddle.net/Vq6gt/125/**

Comment: actually data getting by dynamically.

Comment: Hi,i want searching on popup table and scrolling for table body.It is possible?

Comment: @NavyaPrasad hey i can't understand your requirement can explain it.?

Comment: 1.scroll table body and fixed headers. 2.search names in table.

Comment: @NavyaPrasad here is what you want i am updating in answer you can check it out

Comment: in above code  popup have one table ok in that table body is too long in my original code.So now i want scroll only body part.

Comment: Its good when you mouse over on the record it should be hyper link