# How to display popup selected value in text-box

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I designed one input text-box with button. Once i click the text-box it's shows one popup.Popup contains table with values. Now i selected one value, but it is not displayed in the text-box.

How to get the value? Please guide me.

```
<div>
<label for="name" style="margin: 0px;">EMP NAME</label>
<input type="text" class="input-normal" id="empname" href="#fee-details" data-toggle="modal" style="line-height: initial; margin-left: 6px;">
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="fee-details" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="fee-details-label" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body">
            <table class="table table-condensed">
                <thead class="modal-header login-modal-header">
                    <tr style="width:100%;">
                        <th style="width:50%;">Header1</th>
                        <th style="width:50%;">Header2</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody class="body">
                    <tr>
                        <td>1</th>
                        <td class='val'>A</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>2</th>
                        <td class='val'>B</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>3</th>
                        <td class='val'>C</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>4</th>
                        <td class='val'>D</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>5</th>
                        <td class='val'>E</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>6</th>
                        <td class='val'>F</th>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>          
        </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
</div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
```

```
$('.body').on('click',function(){
    $('#empname').val($(this).find('.val').html());
    $('#fee-details').modal('toggle');
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Twitter bootstrap : How to display popup value in text-box](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33102498/twitter-bootstrap-how-to-display-popup-value-in-text-box)

Comment: Duplicate question . Please view http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33102498/twitter-bootstrap-how-to-display-popup-value-in-text-box

Comment: that code is not working in my testing

Comment: Why you then accept the answer??

Comment: Now my requirement is changed.I posted updated code Please check it once my question.

Comment: @ davidkonrad:sorry i'm new for designing.Your think is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display selected cell(td) value into the text box.You can use following statement in js file.

```
jQuery('.body tr td').on('click',function()
{
   //get cell text currently selected by user and display in the text box
   jQuery('#empname').val(this.firstChild.nodeValue);


});
```

Note-
 this.firstChild.nodeValue - This display text from td selected by you.